# I have deployed the new React code on AWS amplify but the changes are still not visible on the website?? How to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

`On AWS the pipeline is created build and deploy.`

How to solve this issue, any solution like how to clear cache automatically as the new version of code get deployed and changes would be visible.

Comment: Don't know for AWS amplify, but in general for web, the better way to force browsers not under your control to accept new deployed scripts is to modify the script or resource URL. It can be renamed auto according to build process that adds mini hash to it like `/main-1e7cafdef6e37dc8.js`, or manually too by adding GET parameter like `/main.js?v=2.0.3`. If the script URL is not changed, you have no control on the users browsers to force them to clear cache.

Comment: means that I have make changes webpack.config.js right?

Comment: Nope, no need to. I think AWS Amplify does create the file with an automatic hash. Try to compare the script(s) name on deployed server with the one(s) in the browser, to see if it remains the same. If they are the same, then in server if the script content has really been update with the new code. If both server and browser script has same name but different content, then it will be the time to configure Amplify to add a new hash in the files on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing amplify to deploy from your repo, a new addition provides cache invalidation... this is not cache in your browser, but is cache at the cdn level for your entire app.

I am having the same problem, but I deploy manually by uploading 'dist' folder. Can't find help for this on aws or interwebs.

[Reference 1](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2454371-aws-amplify-console-now-supports-instant-cdn-cache-invalidation)

[Reference 2](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/aws-amplify-console-adds-support-for-instant-cdn-cache-invalidation-and-delta-deployments/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Amplify%20Console%20Adds%20Support%20for%20Instant%20CDN%20Cache%20Invalidation%20and%20Delta%20Deployments,-Posted%20On%3A%20Mar&text=The%20Amplify%20Console%20now%20supports,content%20delivery%20network%20(CDN)%20caching)